# Unsupported field: Year when formatting an instant to Date ISO

Tags: java

I am trying to format an Instant to a ldap date ISO8601 but it fails at f.format(Instant.now()); :

```
String input = "20161012235959.0Z";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "uuuuMMddHHmmss[,S][.S]X" );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse ( input , f );
Instant instant = odt.toInstant ();

f.format(Instant.now());
```

And the error is :

```
java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: Year

    at java.time.Instant.getLong(Instant.java:603)
    at java.time.format.DateTimePrintContext.getValue(DateTimePrintContext.java:298)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$NumberPrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2540)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2179)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.formatTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:1746)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.format(DateTimeFormatter.java:1720)
...
...
```

Comment: Have you tried with `yyyy` instead of `uuuu` in the Pattern?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

To format an Instant a time-zone is required.

```
 String input = "20161012235959.0Z";
 DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter
       .ofPattern ( "uuuuMMddHHmmss.SX" ) 
       .withLocale( Locale.FRANCE )
       .withZone( ZoneId.of("UTC"));
 OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse ( input , f );
 Instant instant = odt.toInstant ();

 System.out.println(input);
 System.out.print(f.format(instant));
```

Comment: It solve the error but I obtain something like 20161024083616,2.2+02 instead of something like 20161012235959.0Z

Comment: you format now date so the expected result is `20161024083616,2.2`

Comment: if you want to retrieve the initial string format `instant` instead of `now()`.

Comment: When I format instant it gives 20161013015959,0.0+02 instead of 20161012235959.0Z

Comment: the `Z` means "Zulu time" (UTC), so if you have to retrieve it change the time zone `.withZone( ZoneId.of("UTC"))`.

Comment: @EricReboisson see updated response

Comment: It is better now with DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern ( "uuuuMMddHHmmss[.0]X" ).withLocale(Locale.FRANCE).withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC") );

Comment: but my formatting is delayed with 2 hours . I obtain 20161024084121.0Z instead of 20161024104121.0Z

Comment: remove `withLocale` method

Comment: same problem, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "uuuuMMddHHmmss[.0]X" ).withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")) prints 20161024085656.0Z instead of 20161024105656.0Z

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126500/discussion-between-andolsi-zied-and-eric-reboisson).

Comment: Rather than using the "UTC" string, `ZoneOffset.UTC` can be used