# java conversion from/to asn1 dateTimes

Tags: java, utc

In my framework I need to convert to/from Java Dates and ASN1 UTC Times (Generalized Times). I have tried SimpleDateFormat and OffsetDateTime. Is there a clear simple way to get both directions? The bytes in asn1 are character bytes. For instance below, however I need "YYMMDDhhmmssZ" in bytes.

The decode test passes, due to changes from the first answer, is below:

```
@Test
public void testUTCTimeDecode() throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[] {48, 55, 48, 51, 50, 50, 49, 53, 53, 56, 49, 55, 90};
    ByteArrayInputStream derStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

    Date testDate = new Date(OffsetDateTime.parse("2007-03-22T15:58:17+00:00").toEpochSecond() * 1000);

    byte[] decodeBytes = new byte[bytes.length];
    derStream.read(decodeBytes);

    OffsetDateTime actual = OffsetDateTime.parse(
            new String(decodeBytes),
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuMMddHHmmssX"));

    Date date = Date.from(actual.toInstant());
    assertTrue(date.equals(testDate));
}
```

I am still having an issue with encoding. Here is the exception thrown and the test method:

```
java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: Year
at java.time.Instant.getLong(Instant.java:603)
at java.time.format.DateTimePrintContext.getValue(DateTimePrintContext.java:298)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$NumberPrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2540)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2179)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.formatTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:1746)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.format(DateTimeFormatter.java:1720)
at club.callistohouse.asn1.ASN1TestModel.testUTCTimeEncode(ASN1TestModel.java:47)
```

Here is the test method I am using which is now fixed.

```
    @Test
public void testUTCTimeEncode() throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[] {48, 55, 48, 51, 50, 50, 49, 53, 53, 56, 49, 55, 90};
    ByteArrayOutputStream derStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Date testDate = new Date(OffsetDateTime.parse("2007-03-22T15:58:17+00:00").toEpochSecond() * 1000);

    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(testDate.getTime());
    DateTimeFormatter utcFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
               .ofPattern ( "uuMMddHHmmssX" ) 
               .withLocale( Locale.US )
               .withZone( ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    String formattedDate = utcFormatter.format(instant);
    derStream.write(formattedDate.getBytes());
    assertTrue(Arrays.equals(bytes, derStream.toByteArray()));
}
```

Comment: Without knowing your `ASN1InputStream` and `ASN1OutputStream` classes it’s hard to tell. Would it be possible for you to produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Since you can use `OffsetDateTime`, I recommend you go for a solution without the outdated classes `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `TimeZone`.

Comment: I fixed a cast issue, though the decoding is still failing for parse format. I also enabled the testGeneralizedTime, in addition to testUTCTime.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We could probably help you — and would be glad to — if you could provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example including precise expected and observed output.

Comment: I edited the OP, thank you for helping clear me to a better question, hopefully.

Comment: It’s much better now. Thank you!

Comment: I can run your encoding code without seeing any exception thrown, and the test passes.

Comment: I now have all basic ASN1 types passing tests, including byteArray, time, objectId, utf8 and sequences and sets. Working on definitions and mapping. Thank you for your practical guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

```
    OffsetDateTime expected = OffsetDateTime.of(2007, 3, 22, 15, 58, 17, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    DateTimeFormatter asn1Formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuMMddHHmmssX");
    OffsetDateTime actual = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString, asn1Formatter);
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

### Avoid the outdated date and time classes

I recommend you avoid the outdated classes `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `TimeZone`. The modern Java date and time API, from which you are already using `OFfsetDateTime`, is so much nicer to work with. In particular mixing the two APIs, though possible, is bound to create confusing code.

If for instance in the end you need an oldfashioned `Date` object for a legacy API, only convert from `Instant` to `Date` in the last moment to minimize your use of the old API.

### The bugs in you format pattern string

There are two bugs in your format pattern string:

1. You cannot use uppercase `YY`. This is for week-based year and only useful with week numbers. Use either lowercase `yy` or `uu`, and beware that two-digit year will be interpreted as in the range 2000 through 2099.
2. Format pattern letter `Z` does not match zone offset `Z`. Use `X` in your format pattern instead.

Comment: I was able to get this to work for decoding, but I still have an issue with encoding. The test method and new exception are edited into the original question. I am getting an exception now: java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: Year

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211892/unsupported-field-year-when-formatting-an-instant-to-date-iso

Comment: Is there a way to override the century selection strategy? Simply using the current century is not correct in this context; if the year % 100 falls in some range, it should be the 21st century, otherwise, it should be the 20th.

Comment: @erickson For how to control the century selection, see [Meno Hochschild’s answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29496149/5772882).

Comment: @OleV.V. That API documentation is a bit complex, but sounds like it has potential. Thank you!